# Associate a site from localhost to a domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, localhost

So I have a website, like `http://website.com`.

I also have a "back-up" (development version) of this website on my computer (localhost), including the database and everything.

The problem with this back-up is that I have to change all the script config for it to work, like domain name (to `localhost/website`), paths, database name, pw etc...

How can I access my localhost website from my real domain name? Ie - when I type `http://website.com` in the browser address bar, I want to see my local website backup, just like if I typed `localhost/website`. I want to the scripts to think that they are running under that domain name.

Obviously I only need this temporarily, because I still want to be able to access my live site :)

I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3, running trough WAMP 2.0 (windows 7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows, c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts (Open hosts in notepad) and edit the line starting with `127.0.0.1` ...

```
127.0.0.1 localhost www.website.com website.com
```

and what this does, is makes it so ONLY FOR THAT COMPUTER all requests to website.com will use localhost instead. Hope it helps.

Comment: seems to work, kind of, but I get the root directory (localhost). How can I get the `localhost/website` directory? I tried changing localhost/website in that file but that didn't work :(

Comment: @U4iK your original method actually will break things, since it overrides previous entries (like localhost)

Comment: @Alex that only controls your dns resolution, you'll have to modify your your web server configs to server `localhost/website` as the root

Comment: it works ! I followed the instructions from here: http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/configuring-multiple-domains-within-wamp-for-local-development/ :D

Comment: Glad to hear. Keep us posted on how your server's coming along, as (I'm sure) you will be adding and modifing its code. Hopefully it's as fun as I find it.

Comment: lol I'm scared I'll forget to follow these steps and I make changes to the live site :)

Comment: Well for me, I own a .info domain too, which runs on its own virtual host. The virtual host runs a htdocs2 folder, so as long as I only edit htdocs2 stuff, I'm good. And plus, this way, you get a live site on the net as beta testing. Even add a .htaccess login if you want it protected.